# Python / tkinter: Binding right button click in an array of widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

`enter code here`I am rendering an array of buttons onto the screen and want to implement a right-click function. I have left click working with the default "command=" option on the widget, but for some reason, I can't seem to get the button bind to kick in. My code looks like this:

```
for key, value in sorted_widget_properties:
    if key not in self._filter_list:
        continue
    colour = value[appearance_mode_index]
    if row > 18:
        offset = 4
        row = 1

    # Light mode colours
    if row == 1:
        pad_y = (10, 0)
    else:
        pad_y = 5
    lbl_property = ctk.CTkLabel(master=widget_frame, text=' ' + key)
    lbl_property.grid(row=row, column=1 + offset, sticky='w', pady=pad_y)
    btn_property = ctk.CTkButton(master=widget_frame,
                                 border_width=1,
                                 fg_color=colour,
                                 width=button_width,
                                 height=button_height,
                                 text='',
                                 command=lambda widget_property=key: self.colour_picker(widget_property),
                                 corner_radius=3)
    btn_property.grid(row=row, column=0 + offset, padx=5, pady=pad_y)
    self.widgets[key] = {"widget": btn_property, "button": btn_property, "colour": colour,
                         'label': lbl_property}
    # Set a binding so that we can paste a colour, previously copied into our clipboard
    self.widgets[key]['widget'].bind("<Button-3>",
                                     lambda widget_property=key: self._paste_colour(widget_property))
    row += 1
```

I have a print statement in the _paste_colour class method, and it appears that the function is never called and nothing is ever printed:

```
def _paste_colour(self, widget_property):
    print('PASTE COLOUR!"')
    new_colour = pyperclip.paste()
    if len(new_colour) != 7:
        self._status_bar.set_status_text(status_text='Attempt to paste a bad colour code - ignored.')
    self._set_widget_colour(widget_property=widget_property, new_colour=new_colour)
    self._status_bar.set_status_text(
        status_text=f'Colour {new_colour} assigned to widget property {widget_property}.')
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks,

Clive

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve], preferably one that doesn't rely on customtk, unless customtk is literally causing the problem.

Comment: You need to bind event on `self.widgets[key]['widget'].canvas` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please provide a minimal reproducible example. You have a lot of variables that are not defined in the code you show and the tkinter class is not provided either. Also we do not know if you get any error messages. This makes it difficult to troubleshoot. It might be that you are just missing an `event` parameter, but not sure if I get your issue correctly.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
widget_frame = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=1, column=1)


def right_click(x):
    print('right clicked')
    print(x)

def left_click():
    print('left clicked')


lbl_property = tk.Label(master=widget_frame, text='Label')
lbl_property.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
btn_property = tk.Button(master=widget_frame,
                             text='button',
                             command=left_click
                             )
btn_property.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
param='some parameter'
btn_property.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, x=param: right_click(x))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OK point taken and I should have known better. Based on your example. It appears to be a problem with customtkinter.

Answer (score 0):

OK, apologies, I really should have done a bit more prep.

Anyway, taking the above example and replacing with a `customtkinter` widget. I have reproduced the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
widget_frame = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=1, column=1)


def right_click(x):
    print('right clicked')
    print(x)

def left_click():
    print('left clicked')


lbl_property = tk.Label(master=widget_frame, text='Label')
lbl_property.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
btn_property = ctk.CTkButton(master=widget_frame,
                             text='button',
                             command=left_click
                             )
btn_property.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
param='some parameter'
btn_property.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, x=param: right_click(x))

root.mainloop()
```

Running the above, masks out the right click binding. No errors, just doesn't work.

I'll raise the issue on GitHub on the customtkinter forum.

Comment: This did indeed turn out to be a CustomTkinter issue. The issue is now fixed in CustomTkinter version 5.